# Importing a stored procedure from oracle to Informatica

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have to import a stored procedure from Oracle database into Informatica.
But when I try to use the Stored Procedure Transformation I cannot view the respective stored procedure. 
I am using the correct oracle driver since I don't have any trouble in importing target database tables.
I tried viewing the stored procedures in the oracle database using 
`select * from all_objects where object_type='FUNCTION'` but could not find the
function I am looking for.
Please advise me on these:

- Can we view the list and code of Stored procedure(s)/function(s) in Oracle
- What am I missing in Informatica stored procedure transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get any results from this..

```
select * from all_objects where object_type='FUNCTION'
```

It either means you don't have any functions or the current user does not have the privileges to execute any functions. Find out which user owns the function and grant the following.

example :

```
grant execute on <owner>.<function_name> to ETL_USER;
```

To avoid confusion, make sure the username in the informatica connection and the one you are using when connecting to the database are the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. While importing object into Informatica, listed objects are always owned by the "connecting" user. If your object is owned by some other user, you wont see it.  To see objects not owned by connecting user, you'd have to choose "All" in the schema text box, while connecting.
2. You should  be looking for object_type='PROCEDURE'  and not "FUNCTION". Therefore, your query should read as `select * from all_objects where object_type='PROCEDURE'`
3. If all this is done and you still dont see the object, check privileges on that object to your connecting user.  For this, the best course is 
   a. ask your dba to grant execute privileges on that object to your connecting user. OR
   b. connect to database as the owner of that object and run the following command 
   `grant execute on <object_name> to <connecting_user>`